# Do Not display pagination

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have one question. What I"m attempting to do is if there are no returned results for the table then do NOT display the pagination. What I have no does not work.

```
var oTable = $('#templatesPageList').dataTable( {
    "sDom": 'rti<"pagination"p>',
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "fnDrawCallback":function(){
        if(oTable).find("tbody tr").length(0){
            $(oTable 'div.dataTables_paginate')[0].style.display = "none";
        } else {
            $(oTable 'div.dataTables_paginate')[0].style.display = "block";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do:

```
"fnDrawCallback":function(){
    if((oTable).find("tr").length > 0)){
        $(oTable).find('div.dataTables_paginate').show();
    } else {
        $(oTable).find('div.dataTables_paginate').hide();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This strikes me as a bit strange: `if(oTable).find("tbody tr").length(0){` It will certainly cause errors in JS. Do you mean `if(oTable.find("tbody tr").length == 0){`?

Also: `$(oTable 'div.dataTables_paginate')` won't work. You need to concatenate if you're only passing one argument, or better still, use the original selector: `$('#templatesPageList div.dataTables_paginate')`

Comment: For some reason its just not liking that. Let me make a jsfiddle real quick and I'll repost.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xtremer360/dwPPe/2/   if you notice what is supposed to appear in the table footer doesn't anymore as well.

Comment: I've even tried this:  if(oTable.find("tbody tr").length == 0){
            $('div.pagination').remove();
        }   and it didn't work.

Comment: Ah-HA! Your issue is that the table is never empty. You need to test for this instead: `if($('#templatesPageList tbody td.dataTables_empty').length > 0)` and then toggle appropriately: `$('#templatesPageList').remove()`

Comment: Can I also do: if($('#templatesPageList tbody td.dataTables_empty').length <= 10) that way if it returns 10 or less than 10 records then it removes the div?

Comment: You'll probably need to have: ` if($('#templatesPageList tbody td').length <= 10 || ($('#templatesPageList tbody td.dataTables_empty').length > 0))`

Comment: This works however the part of it displaying 10 rows makes it then not display the pagination. var oTable = $('#templatesPageList').dataTable( {
        "sDom": 'rti<"pagination"p>',
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "fnDrawCallback":function(){
            if($('#templatesPageList tbody tr').length <= 10 || ($('#templatesPageList tbody td.dataTables_empty').length > 0))
                $('div.pagination').remove();
            }
    });

Comment: It looks like you're telling it to only show 10 rows at a time, so `<= 10` will always be true.

Answer (score 0):

Nicola's code did not work for me because table always contain rows (at least header). What did the trick was:

```
"fnDrawCallback": function (o) {
                        if (o.aiDisplay.length > 0) {
                            $("#templatesPageList_paginate").show();
                         } else {
                            $("#templatesPageList_paginate").hide();
                         }
```